# Ubuntu 23.04 resets to wrong dns server on startup

Tags: internet, dns, vpn

I've had this problem since updating to 23.04. When Ubuntu reboots it reboots to the DNS server of Proton VPN. I tried this solution: [Internet connection only work when i use vpn! ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462863/internet-connection-only-work-when-i-use-vpn-ubuntu-22-10?newreg=a8e707e676e34a5fb890d02723076218) which works when I turn the wifi off and back on but upon rebooting Ubuntu changes the DNS server back to the one that Proton VPN uses. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? it also does not change the DNS server back to the one it should be using after stopping Proton VPN.

In the provided solution they say to change the DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `8.8.8.8` but as stated it only works before rebooting.

Comment: Don’t edit `/etc/resolv.conf`. By default it is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, which is the local caching stub resolver. It even states in the file that it is a dynamic file. Changes are not persistent through reboots. With ProtonVPN, their app has a setting called **Kill Switch** that defines when and how external connections are handled when VPN isn’t connected. Check that first.

Comment: @mpboden How do I modify the Kill Switch setting?

Comment: In the ProtonVPN app, there is a button that allows you to change the **Kill Switch** setting. See the ProtonVPN [instructions](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-setup/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out with the help of the Proton team that disconnecting through the app makes the internet work correctly but disconnecting through Ubuntu breaks the internet connectivity.